# How to plot the position vector r(t) = 3 cos(3.3πt)i + (sin(4πt) + 4t)j with t being a min of 0 and max of 1?

Tags: vector, parametric-functions

Every time I try using the ParametricPlot, nothing shows up. This is what i've done so far:

```
ParametricPlot[{[3 cos[3.3 πt]], [sin[4 πt] + 4 t]}, {t, 0,   1},
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please show the code you have written.  Without it, readers can do little to help you.

Comment: Syntax errors: 1) square brackets only for function calls, not for grouping, 2) function names do always start with an uppercase letter, 3) spacing: separate $\pi$ and t with a space otherwise you have a new (single) variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to learn at least the very basics of Mathematica syntax.

```
ParametricPlot[{3 Cos[3.3 π t], Sin[4 π t] + 4 t}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]